# Removing directive from DOM based on child directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I'm writing a permissions lib to add to my angular website.

Each element will have permission attribute:

`<md-button permission="adjust" ng-click="vm.adjust()">Adjust</md-button>`

And a service will check whether the logged-in user has permission to perform the action. The directive's code looks as follows:

```
let permissionActionsDirective = ($compile, actionsService) => {
  return {
    priority: permissionPriority,
    terminal: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
      actionsService.isEnabled($attr.permission)
        .then(()=>{
          $compile($element, null, permissionPriority - 1)($scope);
        },()=>{
          $element.remove()
        })
      }
  };
};
```

This worked great.

Then I encountered a case where all child elements are not permitted, so I'd like to hide the parent as well:

```
<md-menu permission-container ng-if="vm.mode === 'manager'" layout="row">
  <md-button flex ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">Menu</md-button>
  <md-menu-content class="actionMenu">
    <md-menu-item permission="add_user">
      <md-button ng-click="vm.onAdd()">Add user</md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
    <md-menu-item permission="settings">
      <md-button ng-click="vm.settings()">Settings</md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
  </md-menu-content>
</md-menu>
```

So I needed to create permissionContainer directive, and modify the permission directive's code to:

```
let permissionActionsDirective = ($compile, actionsService) => {
  return {
    priority: permissionPriority,
    terminal: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?^permissionContainer',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr, containerCtrl) {
      actionsService.isEnabled($attr.permission)
        .then(()=>{
          _.invoke(containerCtrl, 'allow');
          $compile($element, null, permissionPriority - 1)($scope);
        },()=>{
          _.invoke(containerCtrl, 'deny');
          $element.remove()
        })
      }
  };
};
```

Now my question is how should permissionContainerDirective's code look like?
I want the following behavior:

1. The element that has permission-container attribute will load hidden.
2. If even one child signals by calling permissionContainerController.allow() the item will be shown
3. If none signaled allow() (or all signaled deny()) remove the element from the DOM

I've been trying to modify compile/controller/link functions but can't get it right. Can you help me figure it out?

Thanks!